# Xamarin Label losing text alignment when page returned to

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a label inside of a stack layout. It has its `HorizontalTextAlignment` set to `TextAlignment.Center`. It works correctly on the initial loading of the page, and when a new value is selected - however when the page is left and then returned to, it loses its alignment. This is only a problem on Android and not on iOS. I hope the image below can help illustrate my point. This is the only code that affects the Label's alignment, other than that it's just changing it's text through a binding, but I don't see how that would change it's alignment. Any ideas? Thanks.

```cs
StackLayout durationLayout = new StackLayout {
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
    WidthRequest = (App.ScreenDpWidth / 3) - (GMStyle.Margin.PageMargin.Left * 2),
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0),
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
};
durationLabel = new Label {
    Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["DurationLabelStyle"],
    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    //VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
};
durationLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "DurationDisplay");
durationLayout.Children.Add(timeSpanPicker);
durationLayout.Children.Add(durationLabel);
durationLayout.GestureRecognizers.Add(timeSpanTap);
```

[image]

Comment: I have noticed this problem in an App I am developing, but only on Emulator (Android). On a real device it does not appears. Emulator is Android 7. Device is 4.x....

Comment: Maybe it's a bug on Nougat, it's showing on my physical device running 7.1.1

Comment: I would deploy to an actual device and see if the issue persists. Are you using a tabbed page to navigate?

Comment: I am deploying to an actual device. I'm using a custom tabbed page. But this happens if you tab out and back into the app. Or change any page, whether it's to another tab page or adding a page onto the stack.

Comment: I just run my app on another physical device (running 6.0)..it ran properly. I guess this is an Android 7.0+ bug.

Comment: Is it the child of a grid at any point? There's a long running bug where children of grids lose text alignment that's bad enough that we don't use grids at all anymore. If it is, try replacing the grid with a stack. It looks like your timespanpicker has is missing its top padding in all the screenshots as well

Comment: @Slepz The [Xamarin performance guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment-testing/performance/) advises against replacing a grid layout with stack, but if it's the only way to avoid this bug, I guess there's no choice. I'm getting alignment bugs in some grid layouts after reworking my UI to use grids for that reason. Hopefully this bug is fixed ASAP

Comment: The same thing happens to me, but I'm using a StackLayout nested in another StackLayout. No grid. XF version 2.4.0.280

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a bug in Xamarin Forms, that I believe appeared in 2.3.3 or 2.3.4, it works fine in 2.3.2. I don't know of any bug report lodged against it just yet, this is the closest I could find, that may be related.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=49311

As a workaround, you can use `HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand` instead of `HorizontalTextAlignment`.

Comment: I found that when I replaced `HorizontalTextAlignment=Center` with `HorizontalOptions=CenterAndExpand`, the issue still persisted; but when I included them **both**, the text always displayed centered.

Answer (score 2):

This is bug of xamarin forms. You have to make a custom renderer of label and not to refresh its children drawable state Hope it will work

```
public override void ChildDrawableStateChanged(Android.Views.View child)
{
   base.ChildDrawableStateChanged(child);
   Control.Text = Control.Text;
}
```